# JPA equivalent of Hibernate's @Generated(GenerationTime.ALWAYS)

Tags: java, jpa

When certain **non key** fields of a entity are generated in the database (for instance, by triggers) a call to `persist` will not bring back values that the database has just generated. In practice this means that you may need to `refresh` an entity after `persist` or `merge` (and when level 2 cache is enabled you may even need to `evict` the entity).

Hibernate have a custom annotation [`@Generated`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/Generated.html) which handles [Generated Properties](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch05.html#mapping-generated).

```
// Refresh property 1 on insert and update
@Generated(GenerationTime.ALWAYS) 
@Column(insertable = false, updatable = false)
private String property1;

// Refresh property 2 on insert
@Generated(GenerationTime.INSERT) 
@Column(insertable = false)
private String property2;
```

JPA [`@GeneratedValue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/GeneratedValue.html) only works with primary key properties.

So, my question is if there is a replacement for `@Generated` on JPA API (maybe on 2.1)? And if there isn't one, what is the best practice to handle non key database generated fields?

Comment: Just curious but, why do you need to generate the value for the field?

Comment: Mainly because of triggers that modify non key columns. I need those values and am would like to remove the burden of manually refreshing (and sometimes evicting) entities that where just persisted.

Comment: Given this question was where I ended up recently (2023/Mar/28), it was deflating to see that it was unsolved...in early 2014. However, it turns out things have changed dramatically, as they do in Open Source software. And now there is actually a solution pathway. Here's the one I developed specifically for generating UUID outside of the PK (Primary Key): https://stackoverflow.com/a/75900798/501113

Comment: @chaotic3quilibrium, unless I've missed something, the answer in question is using Hibernate's `@Generated` annotation. Generated was already around back in 2014. My question is exactly about finding a pure JPA alternative to it (e.g., for folks using  other JPA providers such as EclipseLink). I haven't followed it closely, but if an alternative exists or is ever implemented I'll be happy to upvote other answers as well change the accepted answer once verified.

Comment: By the way. As far as I can tell there still isn't an alternative in the latest specs [Jakarta Persistence 3.1](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/3.1/) so apparently the answer bellow is unfortunately still correct.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly Ah. I missed that subtlety. For me and my experience (thus far), JPA and Hibernate are essentially the same thing. Tysvm for clarifying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I read the specs from the beginning until the end and it is not such thing, nothing comparable with @Generated, sorry , and as you said.

> The GeneratedValue annotation may be applied to a primary key property
>   or field of an entity or mapped superclass in conjunction with the Id
>   annotation.

What you could do is use Event Listener **@PrePersist** and **@PreUpdate** to set some properties by default or generated by utility classes before em persist the object , try that approach it comes to my mind to something similiar.

Comment: I was afraid so :(. Unfortunately triggers can be complex and data-centric beasts. Even if I could disable the triggers (and I can't), moving this kind of logic to the application would be a pain. Guess I'm stuck with manually refreshing.