# Non-PK automatic UUID (generated on INSERT by Postgres) is failing a JPA Repository.save() for the matching Entity

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, uuid

I have a pre-existing Postgres table designed to automatically generate a DEFAULT value for a UUID typed column THAT IS NOT THE PRIMARY KEY.

Here's the DDL:

```sql
CREATE SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS uuid_column_table_seq;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS uuid_column_table
(
    uuid_column_table_id     integer  DEFAULT nextval('uuid_column_table_seq') NOT NULL,
    not_pk_uuid              uuid     DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4()               NOT NULL,
    label                    text,
    PRIMARY KEY (uuid_column_table_id)
);
```

And I have a JPA entity (I'm attempting) to match:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "uuid_column_table")
public class UuidColumnTableEntity {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Integer uuidColumnTableId;

  @Column
  @GeneratedValue
  private UUID notPkUuid;

  @Column
  private String label;

  public Integer getUuidColumnTableId() {
    return this.uuidColumnTableId;
  }

  public void setUuidColumnTableId(Integer uuidColumnTableId) {
    this.uuidColumnTableId = uuidColumnTableId;
  }

  public UUID getNotPkUuid() {
    return this.notPkUuid;
  }

  public void setNotPkUuid(UUID notPkUuid) {
    this.notPkUuid = notPkUuid;
  }

  public String getLabel() {
    return this.label;
  }

  public void setLabel(String label) {
    this.label = label;
  }
}
```

When I execute the following code...

```java
var uuidColumnTableEntity = new UuidColumnTableEntity();
uuidColumnTableEntity.setLabel("Test Label");
var uuidColumnTableEntityWithPk = UuidColumnTableEntityRepository.save(uuidColumnTableEntity);
```

...on the JPA repository of `UuidColumnTableEntityRepository.save()`, I am getting an JPA exception of:

`could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [not_pk_uuid\" of relation \"uuid_column_table]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement`

Given I am unable to change the Postgres DDL definition, what do I need to correct in defining my JPA entity?

Versions:

- Java 17
- Spring Boot 2.5.6
- Jakarta Persistence 2.2.3
- Postgres 13.3

---

Note: I searched for some time hoping someone had a nearby answer to this. However, I found scads of questions and answers that are years out of date. And those closer in time were about how to get JPA to generate the value as opposed to reading back the value generated by the Postgres `INSERT`.

Comment: I think this might be triggering a weird bug, but because the annotation `@GeneratedValue` should only be used for the primary key column(s), but here is being used in a non pk column. In his case in particular, can you generate the UUID for `not_pk_uuid` in the code?

Comment: I'm totally good not using `@GeneratedValue` for the `not_pk_uuid` column. I just want the column to get the automatically generated value from Postgres. And given that column is defined as `NOT NULL` in Postgres, then I need an @NotNull annotation on the property in the Java entity, right? And that appears to be failing with a `must not be null` exception in JPA.

Comment: @Augusto I must use the value generated by Postgres. IOW, I am not allowed to generate the UUID on the Java side.

Comment: This isn't covered by JPA, but providers have provider specific options (see EclipseLink's https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/a_returninsert.htm ) as various databases have DB specific support for returning generated data from identity and triggers. I don't know what if any support Hibernate has: the  JPA blessed way would be to mark the column as insertable=false and then read back the entity after flush/commit to get the value; a saveAndFetch approach.

Comment: @Chris I did end up finding, what appears to be, a simpler pathway: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75900798/501113

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@Marco Belladielli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5562053/marco-belladelli)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75899318/501113), I was FINALLY put on the right track to solve this.

**tl;dr:**
Specifically...

- **DO NOT** use the annotation...

  - `@GeneratedValue` - With or without parameters, as it is used exclusive for the PK (Primary Key) generation
  - `@NotNull` - Even though the Postgres DDL explicitly shows the column as `NOT NULL`
- Use the annotation...

  - `@Generated(...)` - With specifically precise parameters
  - `@Column(...)` - Again, with specifically precise parameters

---

**Details:**

The only code changes is to the Entity's batchUuid property. This is what ended up working:

```java
import org.hibernate.annotations.Generated;
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenerationTime;

...

  @Column(insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = false)
  @Generated(GenerationTime.INSERT)
  private UUID notPkUuid;
```

Comment: We've been using this approach on Spring boot 2.7 but moving to Spring Boot 3 which uses Hibernate 6, `GenerationTime.INSERT` has been deprecated and one issue I've encountered is since Hibernate 6, updates don't seem to apply on columns annotated with `@Generated(GenerationTime.INSERT)`  anymore. You would be fine here as you're not intending to update the column but in my scenario we have a default value in the DB schema which can be updated to a different value after the initial insert.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Hibernate's `@Generated` annotation, which indicates that the column you're annotating is generated on the database side and will need to be retrieved after inserting new records with a subsequent select statement.

JPA's `@GeneratedValue` annotation is used to define primary key generation, as others have pointed out, and should not be used here.

Comment: Tysvm for answering! This is a "nearby" answer as your suggestion didn't work as-is. However, it is what put me on the path to a precise answer that did work. I'll post the precise answer so others that follow can leap right to the exact solution (given this specific problem space).